# liip imagine the pictures are not showing

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle, php-deployer

I use liip imagine on symfony 6 and I have a problem with images.

I use deployer.php for the deployment of my project and my images are in a shared folder which looks like this: /var/www/shared/public/images.

the image url looks like this:
https://monurl.fr/media/cache/resolve/miniature/image.png

but it does not display anything despite the image being in the directory. The thumbnail directory is not generated by liip in the public/media/cache directory.

On the other hand I have other images which are not in the shared folder and which are well generated.

Here is the imagine liip file configuration.

```
# Documentation on how to configure the bundle can be found at: 

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/basic-usage.html
liip_imagine:
    driver: "imagick"
    filter_sets:
        miniature:
            cache: default
            quality: 50
            filters:
                scale:
                    dim: [ 400,400 ]
        photos:
            cache: default
            quality: 50
            filters:
                scale:
                    dim: [ 1200,1200 ]
```

If you have an idea how to manage the shared folder of deployer with liip I'm interested. Thanks for your help.